# Passing parameters to C++ compiled exe through cmd

Tags: c++, c++11, batch-file, cmd

For Example, I have compiled a C++ program through Cygwin g++ on my Windows PC. It accepts (`cin`) two `string`s and parses it to return a single `string`.
I am thinking of using it in a batch file. Is there any way I can return the result to the .bat program directly by passing the two strings as arguments without actually executing all the input dialogues. (Something like "`asd.exe -param1,param2`" )
Is it to be implemented in the cpp code end. If so, give me a start where to look upon.

Comment: Are looking for [argc, argv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)?

Comment: Look for command line arguments (see this http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson14.html)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can use input redirection.

Comment: For clarification: You want to take an application that requires user input and make it 'headless' where the required input comes instead from a file that spoofs entering the data so that the application 'thinks' the data was typed in. Correct?

Comment: @MikelF Yep, I just need the result of the program returned or to assign to a variable

Comment: "return the result to a .bat program" This is actually hard. What do you want to do with this out put? An alternative may be very easy such as program2 < program1 < argsfile

Comment: May be helpful: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120731-00/?p=7003

Comment: @user4581301 either `echo` it or assign to a variable `set \p =`

Comment: OK. You have that end then. For the other end I'd just pipe in a file containing the input arguments. `asd < argsfile` where `argsfile` contains `param1 param2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write to stdin u redirect the stdin using

so

```
prog<"params"
```

will execute prog and readin String "params" from std::cin
same as redirecting stdout to file.

The other option would be to put the input parameters as arguments to main

```
main(argv,argc){
```

and read argc as the array of string arguments to the program